Robustness of \peek_analysis_map_inline:n with changed catcode
Background
Following my previous question I try to make compatible the redefinition of the circumflex ^ catcode with the active prime ' defined in vanilla LaTeX or by the package unicode-math.
The problem is that the active prime ' looks further for another prime ' or a circumflex ^ to handle expressions like x''^2. But since I change the catcode of the circumflex ^ from 7 (math superscript) to 12 (other) it fails.
I found a workaround with a copy/paste of appropriate internal macros code, but as it is not a good practice to redefine internal macros, I'm looking for a better solution.
I tried something with \peek_analysis_map_inline:n. My idea is to redefine the active prime ' so that it looks at the next chars and

if another prime ' is found, then continue,
if a ^ is found, then replace it by a standard superscript (catcode 7) and stop,
else stop.

Here is my redefinition of the active prime:
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_prime:
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \g__my_std_prime_tl }
    \peek_analysis_map_inline:n
      {
        \int_case:nnF { ##2 }
          {
            { `' }
            {
              \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ' }
            }
            { `\^ }
            {
              \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \__my_std_superscript: }
              \peek_analysis_map_break:n { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
            }
          }
          {
            \peek_analysis_map_break:n { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl ##1 }
          }
      }
  }

The macros \__my_std_prime: and \__my_std_superscript: are the backups of the standard commands.
This works for what I've tried. But since I'll implement this in a package (the altsubsup package), I would like to be sure that the code is robust. Furthermore, I don't know expl3 very well (I found this after lots of trials and errors).
Questions

Is my utilization of \peek_analysis_map_inline:n correct?
Are there any cases where this might fail?
Is the \peek_analysis_map_inline:n implementation stable, as the manual says "The detailed form of ⟨tokens ⟩ may change in later releases." (The LATEX3 Interfaces, 2024-02-20)?

Example
This should work with and without unicode-math.
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% backup standard superscript and set circumflex command when active
\cs_set_eq:NN \__my_std_superscript: ^
\char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__my_std_superscript:

%% define new prime command
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_prime:
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \g__my_std_prime_tl }
    \peek_analysis_map_inline:n
      {
        \int_case:nnF { ##2 }
          {
            { `' }
            {
              \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ' }
            }
            { `\^ }
            {
              \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \__my_std_superscript: }
              \peek_analysis_map_break:n { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
            }
          }
          {
            \peek_analysis_map_break:n { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl ##1 }
          }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%% backup standard prime and set it to the new definition
\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N '
\tl_new:N \g__my_std_prime_tl
\tl_gset_eq:NN \g__my_std_prime_tl '
\cs_gset_eq:NN ' \__my_prime:
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff{}

%% alter circumflex catcode and mathcode
\catcode`\^=12
\mathcode`\^="8000

%% test if superscript is still working
$ x^3 \qquad x^{abcd} $

%% test prime symbol
$x' \qquad x'' \qquad x''' \qquad x'''' \qquad x'''''$\par
$x' \qquad x'^2 \qquad x''^2 \qquad x'''^2 \qquad x'''^{abcd}$

\end{document}



Regarding (3), anything documented in interface3.pdf is stable, what is called out as unstable is that #1 “both o-expand and e/x-expand to the ⟨token⟩”. You're typesetting #1 directly (I think?), so this shouldn't apply to you.

you also need to skip space I think  \__my_std_prime: should prpbably be a tl variable not a function with no arguments (although these are the same thing, really) \cs_new:Nn \__my_prime: should use the protected form since it uses all kinds of internal assignments.

@DavidCarlisle Many thanks for your answer. Neither vanilla LaTeX nor unicode-math skip spaces (x' ^2 throws an error). Maybe I shouldn't modify it. I edited my question to backup the standard prime with a token list and use the protected form for \__my_prime:.

@jlab ah actually that is true. Thanks for the other changes

(This doesn't answer the specific questions that you asked in the title/body at all, but I think that it solves the problem that you are having.)
Instead of making ^ and _ active and patching the definition of the prime, we can make [ math active and have it handle everything, without needing to patch any commands or modify any other catcodes:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Initialization %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{amsmath} %% Optional

%% Use unicode-math for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX (Optional)
\ifdefined\pdftexversion\else
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Definitions %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter

%% Make [ math active
\mathchardef\altsbsp@lbrak=\mathcode`\[
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\[="8000}

%% Typeset the literal [brackets]
\def\altsbsp@brackets{%
    \altsbsp@lbrak% Open bracket
    \altsbsp@contents% The enclosed contents
    ]% Close bracket
}

%% Typeset the [bracketed] material with an upright font
\def\altsbsp@text{%
    \mathrm{%
        \altsbsp@contents%
    }%
}

%% Get the last node type to see if we should do {[bracketed]} or [upright].
\newif \if@altsbsp@start@

\def\altsbsp@gettype{%
    \expandafter\def%
    \expandafter\altsbsp@type%
    \expandafter{\the\lastnodetype}%
    %
    \ifnum\altsbsp@type=15\relax%
        \@altsbsp@start@true%
    \else%
        \@altsbsp@start@false%
    \fi%
}

%% Check to see if a prime came before a superscript
\def\altsbsp@check@prime#1#2{%
    \if#1\egroup%
        %% \pr@@@t places an \egroup before the closing ], so we need to move it
        %% to the end. We also add a thin space here for better spacing.
        \def\altsbsp@contents{\,#2}%
        \def\altsbsp@after{\egroup}%
    \else%
        %% No prime, so just set the contents to the bracketed material.
        \def\altsbsp@contents{#1#2}%
        \def\altsbsp@after{}%
    \fi%
}

%% Define the left bracket command
{
    %% Make [ temporarily active so that we can define its math active version.
    \catcode`\[=\active
    \global\def[#1#2]{%
        %% Expand \the\lastnodetype before opening the group to see if we're the
        %% first typeset material in this script.
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\altsbsp@gettype%
            %% Grab the argument and save it to \altsbsp@contents.
            \altsbsp@check@prime{#1}{#2}%
            \if@altsbsp@start@%
                %% To see if we're in a script, we check the current math style.
                \mathchoice%
                    {\altsbsp@brackets}% Display style, so typeset the brackets.
                    {\altsbsp@brackets}% Text style, ditto.
                    {\altsbsp@text}%   % Script style, so typeset the text upright.
                    {\altsbsp@text}%   % Scriptscript style, ditto.
            \else%
                %% We're not the first item, so just typeset the literal brackets.
                \altsbsp@brackets%
            \fi%
            \altsbsp@after%
        }%
    }
}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Demonstration %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\demo#1{& $\displaystyle#1$ & \texttt{\detokenize{#1}} \\}
\def\longdemo#1{%
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$\displaystyle#1$} \\
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}} \\
}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r l l}
        Regular brackets        \demo{[xyz]                 }[1em]

        Regular scripts         \demo{a^{abc}_{def}         }[1em]

        Script brackets         \demo{a^[text]_{abc}        }
                                \demo{a^{abc}_[text]        }[1em]

        Primed brackets         \demo{a'''^[text]_{abc}     }
                                \demo{a'^{abc}_[text]       }[1em]

        %% Use {braces} to make the brackets literal
        Regular script brackets \demo{a^{[abc]}_{def}      }
                                \demo{a_{[def]}^{abc}      }[1em]

        %% Lone closing brackets are fine, lone opening brackets need some extra
        %% care.
        Lone brackets           \demo{]\infty, 0]           }
                                \demo{\left[0, \infty\right[}
                                \demo{xyz \left[\right.     }[1em]

        %% Nested brackets need to be protected with braces
        Nested brackets         \demo{[a{[b']}]             }
                                \demo{[a]^[x{[y]}]          }[1em]

        %% Optional arguments are unaffected
        Optional Arguments      \demo{\sqrt[x]{y_[z]^z}     }[1em]

        %% Works with multiple occurrences of [brackets] in a single expression
        Complex Expression \longdemo{
            abc^x + [def]'_[text] + \int'^[text]_{[ghi]}
        }
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}


This gives the same output with or without amsmath, with or without unicode-math, and with any of pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX.

Great work, very clever! I'm impressed. Thank you very much. I needed some time to understand it (and even, I don't fully understand why\lastnodetype=15 means that we are just after the ^). I'm not sure to implement it, as it redefine completely the mechanism I use and then is not fully compatible with existing options and current development. But I'll think about it.

@jlab The script anchor character is a math node, so it shows up as \lastnodetype=15, but \lastnodetype resets to -1 whenever a group begins. In the definition of [, we make sure to expand \lastnodetype before the group begins, so if it expands to 15, then there's nothing between the script anchor and the script contents, but if it expands to -1, then the script group has already been started (by the prime in this case). This is documented in the eTeX manual, but only barely; I pretty much figured it out through blind experimentation.

I think I'll implement it as an option. A new task on my todo list. Thanks again. Accepted answer.
